# Changing url parameter with js without reloading page on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting

is it possible to change parameter in url bar so button onclick the parameter to get changed ? So far I have this:

```
function change_product(){
var url =  'http://www.example.com/index.php?product=805';
var newSrc = '0';
newurl=url.replace(/(product=)[^\&]+/,'$1' + newSrc)
alert(newurl);
}    

<button class="save" type="BUTTON" onclick="change_product();">Copy</button>
```

newurl is correct but how to make it change in the url bar? Is it possible at all without page reload?
thanks in advance !

Comment: in suggested answer I see only reload solutions

Comment: No. location.hash and pushstate are both in the suggested duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at window.history.pushState()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

This allows you to change the URL in the address bar without reloading the page.

Here's the current support: http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate

```
var state = {}, newUrl = "test.html";
window.history.pushState(state, "Page Title", newUrl);
```

So for you something like

```
function change_product(){
    var productId = 805;
    window.history.pushState({productId: productId} , "", "?product=" + productId);
}
```

Firefox currently does use the Page Title but you could set it in the state object then use **window.onpopstate** to get the state object and set the page title (if you need to).

If you need to support older IE browsers there's a few libraries that can help you out (like history.js)